# MacOS Docker Container runs out of space although host has enough space

Tags: macos, docker

### The problem

In a docker container i want to download some packages with nuget. These packages size is around 5 GB. After downloading them they will be unpackaged in a mounted folder, for later use.

When doing this nuget returns an error saying "disk full", although there is several 100GB of space left on the host.

Doing the same thing on windows and linux works fine.

The container is not started with `docker run`, but with `docker compose run`.

### What I've tried

`docker system prune -a`

Restart docker

Increase the memory in the docker preferences to 8GB

Increase the SWAP size to the maximum (4GB is the max)

### My current docker settings

[image]

### Docker version

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.22
 Version:           20.10.12
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.12
 Git commit:        e91ed57
 Built:             Mon Dec 13 11:46:56 2021
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.5.0 (74594)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.12
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.12
  Git commit:       459d0df
  Built:            Mon Dec 13 11:43:56 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.12
  GitCommit:        7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

### Docker compose yaml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  nuget:
    build:
      context: docker_image
      args:
        BASE_IMAGE: "ubuntu:20.04"
    image: nuget
    volumes:
      - /var/cache/nuget/v3-cache:/root/.local/share/NuGet/v3-cache
      - /var/cache/nuget/packages:/root/.nuget/packages
      - /tmp:/nuget_cache
    working_dir: /nuget_cache
    environment:
      - NEXUS_PASSWORD
      - PACKAGES
      - USER=${USER}
    command:
      - /fetch.sh
```

### Fetch script in the image

```
mono /nuget.exe sources add \
      -NonInteractive -Verbosity detailed \
      -name PackageSource_0 \
      -configfile cfg.xml \
      -source <my_source> \
      -username ovation-tests -password "${NEXUS_PASSWORD}"

for pkg in ${PACKAGES}; 
do
  echo "Installing ${pkg}..."
  mono /nuget.exe install "${pkg}" \
      -NonInteractive -Verbosity detailed \
      -packagesavemode nuspec \
      -OutputDirectory . \
      -ConfigFile cfg.xml \
      -source PackageSource_0
done
```

Comment: please add the compose file

Comment: I've added the docker-compose to the post